# Posting a JSON to the Salesforce REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, deserialize

I am trying to post the JSON to the Salesforce REST API, JSON getting posted to the REST service is like below

```
[{"manager":"ABC",
"name":"XYZ",
"userSubmitting":"abc@abc.org"}]
```

which comes with the extra `[]` When I deserialize the JSON in the APEX like below

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/newUserCreationProcessor/*')
global with sharing class newUserCreationProcessor{  
    @HttpPost
    global static ProcessorResult doPost(){
        ProcessorResult result = new ProcessorResult();
        
        try {
            RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
            System.debug('Salesforce Integration Works!');
            String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
            Type resultType = Type.forName('NewUserCreationProcessor.userData');
            userData caseSubmission = (userData)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, resultType);
            
            
            ID bhAccountID = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account'].Id;
            
            ID caseQueueID = [Select ID from Group where Type = 'Queue' and Name = 'Salesforce Support'].Id;
            
            List<Contact> c = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, email, AccountId from contact where email =: caseSubmission.userSubmitting];
            Case newCase_Comp = new Case();
            newCase_Comp.OwnerId = caseQueueID;
            newCase_Comp.ContactId = c[0].Id;
            newCase_Comp.AccountId= c[0].AccountId;
            newCase_Comp.RecordTypeId =Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Salesforce Support').getRecordTypeId();
            newCase_Comp.Subject= 'New User Creation';
            insert newCase_Comp;
            
            Id parent_CaseId = newCase_Comp.Id;
            
            String comment1 = 'Name : ' + caseSubmission.name +'\n\r' +
                              'Manager : ' + caseSubmission.manager;
            
           
            CaseComment caseComment1 = new CaseComment();
            caseComment1.ParentId = parent_CaseId;
            caseComment1.IsPublished = true;
            caseComment1.CommentBody = comment1;
            insert caseComment1;
                                     
            result.Message = 'Success';           
        }
        
        catch (Exception ex) {
            result.Message = ex.getMessage();
        }   
        return result;
    }
    
    //Define Model
    global class userData{           
        public String name{ get; set; }
        public String manager{ get; set; }
        public String userSubmitting {get; set;} 
    }
    global class ProcessorResult
    {        
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }}
```

The issue is when I try to test the API I get the error `{"Message": "Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object"}` . How can I omit the [] before deserializing the JSON.. I have limited control over the incoming JSON and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This JSON:

```
[{"manager":"ABC",
"name":"XYZ",
"userSubmitting":"abc@abc.org"}]
```

is a list.

You are deserializing a single object:

```
userData caseSubmission = (userData)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, resultType);
```

Inasmuch as `userData` otherwise matches the schema of the JSON object, you must deserialize a `List<userData>`:

```
List<userData> caseSubmission = (List<userData>)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, List<userData>.class);
```

Comment: Thank you I tried changing to the list and referring caseSubmission[0]  for accessing the data of each fields but still I get the same error `{"Message": "Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object"}`

Comment: The value of `resultType` is presumably wrong. You don't need to use dynamic access there anyway, but you'll have to make it refer to a list.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove those brackets from the string before deserailzing it.

```
String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
 requestBody.removeStart('[').removeEnd(']');
```